# Passing Firebase Data to Function in CollectionTableCellModel

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, collections

I'm having a hard time passing my value I retrieved from my Firestore into my table. I see the value is coming through but only in that particular function. Any idea to get the variable out of that scope only. I tried declaring the variable as an empty string at the top but it returned as an empty string. Thanks!

```
docRef.getDocument {  (document, error) in
            if let document = document, document.exists {
                let title = document["title1"] as? String ?? ""
            let title2 = document["title2"] as? String ?? ""
            
            models.append(.collectionView(models: [
        
        
        CollectionTableCellModel(title: title, imageName: "image"),
        CollectionTableCellModel(title: "title 2", imageName: "image"),
        CollectionTableCellModel(title: "title 3", imageName: "image"),
        CollectionTableCellModel(title: "title 4", imageName: "image")
    ],
    rows: 2))
            
            print("Test \(title1) and \(title2)")
        } else {
            print("Document does not exist")
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Did you try to reload your table inside getDocumets callback after appending new models?

Comment: Yes and I tried w/o appending the original model

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [the delegation pattern](https://medium.com/@nimjea/delegation-pattern-in-swift-4-2-f6aca61f4bf5).

Pretty much you have your async closure being executed in the background thread:

```
{
  model.append(CollectionTableCellModel...)
}
```

What you need is to define a Delegate protocol (to delegate the responsibility to receive and show this data):

```
protocol MyDelegate {
  func didReceiveData(_ data: [CollectionTableCellModel])
}
```

Define and variable at your class:

```
class MyClassThatShouldPresentTheData: MyDelegate {
  func didReceiveData(_ data: [CollectionTableCellModel]) {
     // remember to send this data to the main thread so you can update the ui
     DispatchQueue.main.async {
       collectionView.reloadData()
     }
  }
}
```

And finally in your firebase call you can delegate the responsibility to display the data:

```
var delegate: MyDelegate?

docRef.getDocument { [weak self] (document, error) in 
  let parsedData = ...
  self?.delegate.didReceiveData(parsedData)
}
```

Points to consider if this approach still is not working:

- Any view updates must be done in the main thread
- Check if your delegate is defined
- Use breakpoints to find out if the data is being parsed correctly and if the data is returning from the backend
- Check if the error variable (from the firebase) is returning any value